# Remove or override an emphasis animation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I will give a super basic example since my use case is a bit more complex.

In simple terms I want to "highlight" individual items as I talk about each, but at the end "reveal all" so the big idea can be seen. The problem I am having is emphasis animations can either only have a time element or when `end of slide` is reached which means it will not end until the next slide. However, I have some additional things I want to display before we reach the `end of slide`.

I have 3 pictures and have them animated in the following way.

1. Click - Entrance Animation (Pic. A)
2. Click - Emphasis Animation (Fade Pic. A) - Entrance Animation (Pic. B)
3. Click - Emphasis Animation (Fade Pic. B) - Entrance Animation (Pic. C)
4. **Issue Here:** Click - Entrance Animation (Show Pics. A, B, and C not faded)
5. Other animation elements not tied to the pictures

I originally made step 4 an entrance animation to just instantly display all 3 pics thinking it would overwrite the previous animations that are above it but that does work; although the extra click is needed to actually start item 5 (2 clicks). Essentially I want to "remove" all the fade emphasis animations.

**Please provide the steps in your explanation so I can follow along if this is possible.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. **Apparently the same emphasis animation type can override an earlier use.** My command steps were as follows:

1. Click - Entrance Animation (Pic. A)
2. Click - Emphasis Animation (Fade Pic. A) - Entrance Animation (Pic.
   B)
3. Click - Emphasis Animation (Fade Pic. B) - Entrance Animation (Pic.
   C)
4. **Fix:** Click - Emphasis Animation (Change Fade transparency to 0% - Pics. A, B)
5. Other animation elements not tied to the pictures